# Spring security: adding of custom login-page url cause 403 error code

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I have such `security-context.xml` file:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/user" access="hasRole('ROLE_REGISTERED_USER')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/ticket" access="hasRole('ROLE_BOOKING_MANAGER')"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user password="password" name="user" authorities="ROLE_REGISTERED_USER" />
            <security:user password="password" name="manager" authorities="ROLE_BOOKING_MANAGER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

And it works as expected, but when I add:

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login.html" />
```

I was redirected as expected to my custom `login.html` but after authentication I get `403 Access denied` error code.

Is anyone aware what is wrong?

Comment: You can also try this : <security:form-login login-page="/login" />

Comment: This error seem to make sense bcse you have already created a secured session for this page.  Or because your login.html is outside the WEB-INF folder.